# Problemas con la gema de Tawk.to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

actualmente estoy intentando enlazar la burbuja de chat de Tawk.to a mi sitio web, ya he instalado la gema oficial de RoR en mi gemfile y he realizado los pasos que describe en la documentación (dejo abajo el link). El problema es que cuando inicio mi servidor, la burbuja no aparece y observando en la consola del navegador (F12); me figura un error en donde el link de referencia a mi cuenta de tawk.to se repite (les dejo la imagen ilustrativa).

Alguien sabe en donde puedo modificar el código del render para poder solucionar el problema?

Documentación de la gema: https://github.com/luizpicolo/tawk-rails

[image: Error de consola]

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que no estás proporcionando un *ID de sitio* válido; para obtnerlo necesitas una cuenta de **Tawk**.

Sigue estos pasos para obtener tu *ID de sitio* y configurar correctamente tu aplicación:

1. Abre una cuenta (es gratis) en la [página de Tawk](https://www.tawk.to/).
2. Activa tu sitio siguiendo los pasos mostrados en pantalla (te solicitará una URL válida<sup>1</sup>).
3. Dentro del *dashboard* (al que llegas al finalizar tu registro) da clic en el engrane del menú (*Administrar*). luego en *Configuración de la propiedad* y copia el texto que está en *ID del sitio* (que será algo similar a `79a43470b6e707673de0a162`)
4. Abre el archivo *config/initializers/tawk.rb* y pon el *ID del sitio* que copiaste como valor de `id.site`; por ejemplo:

   ```
   TawkRails.configure do |config|
     config.id_site = '79a43470b6e707673de0a162'
   end
   ```
5. Reinicia tu servidor local.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *No necesitas proporcionar la URL final de tu sitio (la puedes cambiar después), cualquier URL válida (una de prueba, por ejemplo) es suficiente para que te den tu ID y puedas probar en tu ambiente local.*</sup>

Comment: Hola Gerry, el texto ACÁ_VA_MI_ID lo puse con el objetivo de ocultar mi ID original de tawk.to; cualdo coloco directamente mi ID me aparece el error al cual hago referencia con la imagen.

Comment: @rolex92 Entiendo. ¿Podrías mostrar el código relacionado que has utilizado?

Comment: ok, la verdad ahora mismo no tengo acceso a ese código; pero lo que hice fue instalar la gema de tawk.to (la encontré en la página oficial de rubygems); y seguí las instrucciones de la documentación que esta en github. https://github.com/luizpicolo/tawk-rails

Comment: @rolex92 No logro reproducir el error, ¿es visble que generes un repositorio para poder probar con tu código? Igual que en tu ejemplo, no pongas tu id.

Comment: https://github.com/rolotorres/Blog.git --> este es el repositorio del proyecto

Comment: @rolex92 Hice un _fork_ a tu projecto, puse mi ID de tawk y funcionó sin problemas. ¿Podría ser que tu cuenta de Tawk presente algún problema?

Comment: @rolex92 [En este enlace](https://rolotorres.herokuapp.com/) puedes verlo funcionando; no cambie nada más que mi ID y la bd de producción.

Comment: Realmente es extraño.... tendría algo que ver el editor de código?

Comment: @rolex92 No creo, posiblemente tenga algo que ver con la configuración de tu ambiente local. Valdría la pena probar tu código en otra plataforma; yo probé con Mac (local) y Ubuntu (heroku).

Comment: mi entorno local es Ubuntu; aún no lo he subido a un servidor de producción.  Agradezco inmemsamente tu ayuda....

Comment: @rolex92 Podría probar con tu ID de sitio, si no tienes inconveniente (al final del día será público cuando publiques el sitio). En caso que aceptes podrías pasármelo a través del chat de tawk en el [link de prueba](https://rolotorres.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: @rolex92 Sólo para confirmar: ¿exactamente como estás agregando el código en _config/initializers/tawk.rb_? Verifica que únicamente incluyas el _ID_ (no el URL completo); por ejemplo: `config.id_site = '79a43470b6e707673de0a162'`.

Comment: @Garry... solamente introduzco el ID de mi cuenta de tawk.to en el archivo tawk.rb; y aún así, me da error al momento de cargar el chat en Welcome.html.erb

Comment: @rolex92 Desafortunadamente no creo que pueda ayudarte pues no logro reproducir el problema y no sé que puede estar ocasionándolo. :(

Comment: esto es extraño, el error se soluciono solo! ahora ya funciona el render <%= tawk_init %>

Comment: @rolex92 Excelente! Si llegas a encontrar que ocasionó el problema por facor compártelo.

Comment: @Garry, lo único que puedo aportar para solucionar es reiniciar la máquina....